# ASP.NET Identity version 3 with MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-mvc-5

i know we can use **asp.net identity 3** with ASP.NET **core** application but can we use this version of asp.net identity with MVC5 application ? I think we can only use asp.net identity 2 with a MVC5 application but i'm not sure. I have a MVC5 application and i don't want to transform it to a core application. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asp.Net Identity 3 has specifically been written for Asp.Net Core. And since Asp.Net Core has major changes you cannot use Asp.Net Identity 3 with Asp.Net 4.5. If you do not want to upgrade to Core you'll have to stick to version 2.

You can however consider to remove authentication from your application. An alternative may be to implement IdentityServer4 (Core) for the server and using IdentityServer3 (4.5) packages for the application.

https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Getting-Started-with-IdentityServer-4

Comment: Thank you so much Ruard.